# Android Bluetooth Chat Example

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

For a few days now, I have analysed android's bluetooth chat example in their API's. I'm trying to modify the example so that I can send serialized objects over. However, I'm not having any luck so far. I've tried everything. I just want to send objects over bluetooth. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

```
byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
Object o = toObject(readBuf);
System.out.println("MESSAGE_READ:  " +readMessage);//this is being called multiple 
//times from a thread. hence, the object is being constructed only partially. how
//do i resolve this?

public Object toObject (byte[] bytes)
{
  Object obj = null;
  try {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream (bytes);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream (bis);
    obj = ois.readObject();
  }
  catch (IOException ex) {
    //TODO: Handle the exception
  }
  catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    //TODO: Handle the exception
  }
  return obj;
}
```